# Tf command + login server

Tags: tfs, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I try to make some connection to an tfs server.
I must run this in the scheduler, so i need to provide the username and password.

As you can see. We use the tfspreview version. With username ( LIVE ID mailadres ) and password.

When i remove the password. It works. Username and password in cache? I removed cache in the local appdata!

When we try with the password. We get the following error.

```
    TF30064: You are not authorized to access the server.
```

The code we use.

```
            REM @echo off
            REM ... Change the path below. This is the path where the code will be downloaded!
            REM Z:
            REM cd Backup_TFS_Preview
            REM call %VS100COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat x86

            REM ... Navigate to folder
            Z:
            cd Backup_TFS_Preview

            REM ... Makes folder with date today
            mkdir %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%

            REM ... Navigate to folder
            cd %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%

            REM ... Add workspace for the folder with date of today
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" workspace /login:username(LiveID mail adres),password /new /server:https://*.tfspreview.com/DefaultCollection %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4% /noprompt 

            REM ... Get all items from TFS
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" get /recursive /all /noprompt

            REM ... Navigate to folder
            cd ..

            REM ... Zip the folder
            C:\TFS_Backup_Scripts\7z.exe a %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%.zip %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%\

            REM ... Remove folder
            rmdir %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4%\ /s /q

            REM ... Delete workspace
            "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\tf" workspace /delete %Date:~-10,2%-%Date:~-7,2%-%Date:~-4,4% /noprompt

            REM ... Navigate to folder
            cd ..
            cd ..

            REM ... Delete zip files that are older then 10 days 
            forfiles -p "Z:\Backup_TFS_Preview" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del /q @path"

            PAUSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to connect to the tfspreview from the TF.EXE command of Visual Studio 2010, right ?

Even if you installed the QFE to enable TFSPreview access in Visual Studio be aware that this is mainly a "limited patch" and that TF.EXE is not fully compliant with TFSPreview.

You should install the VS11 beta and use the TF.EXE from this version, maybe you'll be more lucky.

Btw I see you're determined to create a schedule job to backup TFSPreview sources. You have to know that even if the platform is in preview state your whole Team Project Collection will be kept 3 months after the TFSPreview gets RTM and you'll be notified several time of the possibility to:

1. Upgrade to the "paid version"
2. Retrieve the Team Project Collection in local before it's destroyed from the MS servers.

Brian Keller from MS was very clear about that. So don't be afraid to loose your code.

**Update:**
[Comment](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/03/27/announcing-a-build-service-for-team-foundation-service.aspx#10288158) from Brian Harry (one of the TFS Big bosses):

> Brian Harry MS 27 Mar 2012 1:06 PM  That said, let me repeat a few
>   things I've said before:
>
> 1) Our goal is to be cost competitive with the market for similar
>   capabilities.
>
> 2) I mentioned in my CodePlex post the other day that we envision a
>   unified service across TFSPreview/CodePlex that scales from free to
>   paid - details still to be determined there.
>
> 3) **Before we institute any billing model, we will provide a high
>   fidelity and easy way to migrate your data from the cloud to an
>   on-premises TFS server should you decide that's more economical**.

Feel free to contact Brian on his blog to ask him a confirmation, he always answers to people.

Comment: Yes i try to connect to tfspreview with the TF.EXE ( VS 2010 ). Hmm, indeed that could be the problem.   In the Terms and Condition, there is line that says that code could be removed without any notification. :(

Comment: No no, I can assure you it won't be the case... If you want me to find the comment from Brian Keller I could search for it. But don't worry. Several MVP and I are using it and MS assured us we will be able to put back the TPC on premise if we don't want to upgrade to the paid version.

Comment: If you would like to search for it. So i can submit it to my manager. The reason why we need that backup was because the Terms And Conditions.

Comment: Thx, i sended him an email. :)

Comment: What I don't understand is why you bother giving a password if it's working without?